# Can we restrict the usage of credential in Jenkins to some users only?

Tags: jenkins

I want to create a credential (to access my GitHub) that can be only used by me in Jenkins. What are the steps to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use [Folders](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin) plugin, it allows to store credentials for specific folder.
In conjunction with Folders plugin you can use [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) plugin (or [Role-Based Access Control](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/plugins/rbac/) plugin for CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise) to restrict user access for some folders.

Or you can use [Authorize Project](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin) plugin to run project as specific user and store your credentials in the per user store (usually in `http://<JENKINS_IP>:<JENKINS_PORT>/user/<USERNAME>/credentials/store/user/`)